Automate the response on youtube video comments
I'm looking to automate replies to comments made on my YouTube videos. I want to set up a webhook and subscribe to specific events. When someone comments on a video, I'd like to receive an event on my webhook so I can respond accordingly.
I've found documentation for adding comment and reply to specific comment. but I haven't found anything about subscribing those events. Is there a way to subscribe to comment events, or is there an alternative approach I should consider?

As YouTube Data API v3 CommentThreads: list endpoint returns results chronologically from the most recent one, thanks to allThreadsRelatedToChannelId filter you can regularly poll this single URL and retrieve last comments on all the channel videos.
